# How to read ros2 bag file in a node

Tags: ros, ros2, rosbag, bagfile, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I was wondering is there a better method to read ros2 bag files inside the ros2 node, I just want to send a command to run the bag files.
The only source I found is [this](https://github.com/ros2/rosbag2/blob/rolling/rosbag2_py/test/test_sequential_reader.py) but this requires me to include this package in my workspace, which I am trying to avoid it or might be I am not importing that library properly. I assume there might be a better solution that can help me to do this.
Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/403077/how-to-read-ros2-bag-file-in-a-node/) by [Flash](https://answers.ros.org/users/67657/flash/) on ROS Answers with karma: 126 on 2022-06-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
Just in case anyone wondering how to solve this there is one non-ROS method. I used the `subprocess` package from python to do that.

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen(['/bin/sh', '-c', 'ros2 bag play '+bag_file_path+'/'])
process.communicate()
process.terminate()
```

this way I send a command to the terminal which will run a bag file and on another end my ROS topic will read it.
This is not the best way I assume but it's the least coding way I was able to do it. But still, if anyone has a better solution or `ROS` solution please let me know.
Just to give a background about the problem I am running the `test node` which subscribes to `topics` and then does some testing on that data. For that, I need the `sensor data` that I can either read from hardware or from the bag file.

---

Originally posted by [Flash](https://answers.ros.org/users/67657/flash/) with karma: 126 on 2022-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0